# Chernoff bound $ \mathbb{P} \left\lbrace \Big| X - \mathbb{E}(X) \Big| > t \right\rbrace $

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, inequality, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

How to apply the Chernoff bound to upper bound the following probability:

$$
\mathbb{P} \left\lbrace  \Big|  X - \mathbb{E}(X) \Big| > t \right\rbrace
$$

where $X$ follows the distribution given as:
\begin{equation*}
P(X=0)=0;
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
P(X=m)=\binom{n-1}{m-1} p^{m-1}(1-p)^{n-m} \ \ \mathrm{for} \ \  m=1,...n ;
\end{equation*}

This is not exactly a binomial distribution but very similar. The term  $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is the expected value of $X$ and $t >0$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh yes sorry.  I will fix it.

Comment: Is this $1$ more than a binomial random variable with parameters $n-1$ and $p$?

Comment: This is a shift by one to avoid the possibility that the random variable X takes the value 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X=Y+1$ where $Y\sim Binom(n-1,p)$. So If $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ are i.i.d. random variables, $Y_i\sim Bernoulli(p)$, then $Y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} Y_i$. 
Apply the Chernoff bound on $Y$. 
The same estimation holds for $X$, as $X-E(X)\sim Y-E(Y)$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why the estimation will hold for X and Y ? I can not see it.

Comment: What do you mean by two cases?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: The Chernoff bound specifically applies to sums of bounded, independent variables. So you can directly apply it to $Y$. Once you do it, you obtain some estimate for the probability $P(|Y-E(Y)|>t)$. In my post, I explained that the same estimate holds for $P(|X-E(X)|>t)$. So you don't want to apply the Chernoff bounds to $X$, as it is not possible directly. Apply it on $Y$.

Comment: Thank's, my concern is to know if saying that  $X - \mathbb{E}(X) \sim  Y - \mathbb{E}(Y)$ is rigorous enough.

Comment: If two random variables $A$ and $B$ have the same distribution, then $P(A>t)= P(B>t)$ for all $t$. So yes, it is "rigorous enough".